# What laptop pre-loaded with Ubuntu can I get with a pointing stick?

Tags: laptop, hardware, trackpoint

Are there any manufacturers who ship laptops with Ubuntu as the default OS and also have a pointing stick (trackpoint)? I found several companies like System76 who have great-looking laptops, but none have the trackpoint. I have been a Thinkpad user for 10 years now and can't imagine not having a trackpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it myself but [Lenovo Toucan](http://www.emperorlinux.com/mfgr/lenovo/toucan/) is one I found a long time ago. Looking at the price, you may be better off buying a thinkpad with free dos and [installing Ubuntu yourself](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/models?form.search_text=Lenovo&form.hardware_category=LAPTOP).